# Java. Почему при выводе в консоль возвращает не ссылку?

Tags: java, массивы, char

Обучаясь java, обнаружил интересную и непонятную для себя особенность с выводом в консоль массивов. Если кратко, переменная-массив, при объявлении, создании и инициализации, как я понял, содержит в себе ссылку на "контейнер/ячейки" в памяти в котором/рых находятся значения/объекты, в зависимости от типа массива. Так вот, если передать в метод out.println(nameArray) имя этой самой переменной-массива то в консоли будет так называемый хэш-код или по другому ссылка на ранее упомянутый "Контейнер", НО! если создать и заполнить массив типа char[] и передать методу out.println() его имя то в консоли выведет **содержимое массива** без пробелов и в одну строку несмотря на print**ln**. Почему так происходит? Почему показывает не ссылку, а содержимое?
вот пример кода:

```
int[] numArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
char[] charArray = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};    
System.out.println(numArray);
System.out.println(charArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть документацию объекта `PrintStream` (именно у этого объекта вы вызываете метод `println()` когда пишите `System.out.println()`) то можно заметить что существует несколько перегруженных методов `println()`. Нас же в данном случае интересует 2 из них, это    `print​(char[] s)` (вызывается когда передается `charArray` из вашего примера) и `print​(Object obj)` (вызывается когда передается `numArray`). Так вот если заглянуть в эти методы и посмотреть их реализацию то она будет немного отличаться (в зависимости от версии java которую вы используете реализация может быть немного разная, но суть остается та же). 
В методе `print​(Object obj)` происходит следующий вызов `String s = String.valueOf(x);` и далее выводится `s` это и есть ваш hashCode по сути. 
А вот в случае с вызовом `print​(char[] s)` массив символов передается на вывод как есть, т.е. по сути этот массив символов воспринимается как строка (с другой стороны если совсем грубо то класс String это обертка над массивом символов), поэтому вы и видите символы из вашего массива как есть, а не хэш-код как вы того ожидаете